# Lagrange inversion theorem for the normal cumulative distribution

Tags: taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions, lagrange-inversion

The Lagrangian inversion theorem gives the Taylor series expansion for the inverse of a function. I was wondering how to apply it to the normal cdf:
$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)dt,
$$
where $g(t)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}e^{-t^2/2}$. Following the notation in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem, how that applies to $f(x)$, what are $a$ and $f(a)$ in this case?

cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You have apparently chosen to confuse yourself by reusing $g$ in a second way.  Therefore, we do not use the function $g$ from the wiki page you cite.

Since
$$  f'(x) = g(x) > 0  $$
and $g(x)$ is analytic everywhere, you are free to pick any $a \in \Bbb{R}$.

For instances,

- randomly choosing $a = 0$, $f(0) = 1/2$;
- randomly choosing $a = -1$, $f(-1) = \frac{1}{2} (1 - \mathrm{erf}(1/\sqrt{2}))$;
- randomly choosing $a = \pi$, $f(\pi) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + \mathrm{erf}(\pi/\sqrt{2}))$; and
- for any choice of $a$, $f(a) = \frac{1}{2}(1 +\mathrm{erf}(a/\sqrt{2}))$,

Where "erf" is the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Let's apply this with $a = 0$, so $f(a) = 1/2$ and
$$  f^{-1}(z) = 0 + \sum_{n-1}^\infty g_n \frac{(z - 1/2)^n}{n!}  \text{.}  $$
Here we find we are getting a power series centered at $1/2$.  Since $f(x) \in (0,1)$, you may center your power series anywhere in that interval.  (Since you want an inverse function, you *cannot* center it anywhere else -- the center is a point of convergence of the series and you want a series that converges on the range of $f$, so the series must be centered somewhere in the range of $f$.  I picked $a = 0$ so the center would be at $1/2$, so there was some chance the series would converge over the entire range.  The inverse function has singularities at $0$ and $1$, so both endpoints place constraints on the radius of convergence of the series.)

Then
$$  g_n = \lim_{w \rightarrow 0} \frac{\mathrm{d}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{d}w^{n-1}}\left( \left( \frac{w - 0}{f(w) - 1/2} \right)^n \right)  \text{.}  $$
The first few terms of the resulting series are
$$  f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{2\pi}(x - 1/2) + \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi^{3/2}}{3}(x-1/2)^3 + \frac{7 \pi^{5/2}}{15\sqrt{2}}(x-1/2)^5 + \frac{127\pi^{7/2}}{315\sqrt{2}}(x-1/2)^7 + \frac{4369 \pi^{9/2}}{11340 \sqrt{2}}(x-1/2)^{9}+ \cdots  $$

Everything in the coefficients except for the sequence $1, 1, 7, 127, 4369, 34807, \dots$ is straightforward to extract into a general term.  That sequence of coefficients in the numerator is OEIS A092676.  The description of that sequence gives a procedure to produce this sequence of coefficients that are part of the $g_n$ coefficients (in the "`%p c:=proc(n)` ..." item).

Comment: Dear Erik, only now I could look at this problem. Sorry if I am not getting the idea. I didn't understand why we need to search for a sequence on oeis. Can't we just use maple to obtain the derivatives for a given number of terms of the inversion formula?

Comment: @Ludwig : The Question doesn't ask for a crappy polynomial approximation to the inverse function, it asks for the inverse function, which requires all the coefficients.  Consequently, a complete answer gives a general technique to generate all the coefficients.  And, just for fun, how long will you have to wait for Maple to find the limit of the 100th derivative of the 100th power of the given ratio with 6 digits of precision and accuracy?  (I gave up waiting after an hour.)

Comment: I see, I was expecting to have a good precision with just a few terms, say 5, something that I need to check. Maple can't handle larger orders, for this problem the 8th sticks maple. You are suggesting to use the pre-computed sequences to avoid that, right?

Comment: @Ludwig : I'm suggesting using the recursive definition at the OEIS entry to avoid ridiculously long derivative calculations to get enough terms to achieve whatever precision and accuracy goals you have.